# How i can make StackPanel with horizontal orientation, center align and streched?

Tags: wpf

I need horizontal oriented StackPanel with centered aligned content. But when i set HorizontalAligment to 'Center', StackPanel shrink to content (Image). I need all area of panel for determination mouse cursor over it.

I understand - the StackPanel is like queue where we put items one after one. But why it cant be stretched and aligned by center?

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="panels.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:panels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF0019E8">
            <Image Source="/icon.png" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

i can do HorizontalAligment=Strech: [Variant 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPLCa.jpg)
i can do HorizontalAligment=Center: [Variant 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEOBs.jpg)
but need something like this: [Variant 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T38Zt.jpg)

Comment: @Clemens, i tried this, but Grid with one cell used similar behaviour :(

Comment: @Clemens, I tried this. It could be good idea, but when i add more than one elements they are have equal position and cover each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to get the result you want is to wrap your StackPanel in a container (e.g Grid) which will be stretched:

```
<Window x:Class="panels.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:panels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF0019E8">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="/icon.png" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The background and the mouse events you want to handle can be based on the Grid.